# Why field type could not be inferred when using decorator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator

Here is the [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDC4rQN4FgBQ0-QDNwBzALmgCMB7KkBMAOwG4d9pgqGIAXAJwFdg3KrwAUASgys2+bgAsAlhAB0RMMWgBeQmBAQELXPgC+OU9hwF+DIQs7Q5kACoCEAMRIAeJ9AQAPbgQGABMYBgQAd2hRZViAB14qOIhyRgBPAG0AXUlNAD44RBRICDzRCkRyJ3FybjS4hCoCSkRoADIMaHCIiXJ0QhJa12hjEakjPF4Ebn5eBnZUGH9AkJgK-XGZfDUyaD5+A2ktji59oREY+MTk1IZMnKwJrfwIfgaxWOUEpIhxQ2eZPIlKoSFo9q5-s9zGxzOYcDgAAKOCAuA4edQ4UAlaAACWcrnRxGKUAAjL4AkFQoV9MSYP04dgTjxcfi0SRaQAmMHI1HuEiiLFoZaUmDwGmLTrGP7wxmcZkUMnaboslEE9mLEkSEHqQxM7iULlKyIq3mEzlanaGHAAegAVNAFPNiEEELwwIFgtBlMFlNwYAQFHQcMEEFipuw5fqFeRqLR6Mxg6HwOG9QaYzQ6IxDLbrTggA):

```js
// index.ts
class BaseClass {
    flag: boolean;
    constructor() {
        this.flag = false;
    }
}

function hasTrueFlag<T extends new (...props: any[]) => BaseClass>(base: T): typeof base & { new(): { flag: true } } {
    return class extends base {
        flag: true;
        constructor(...props: any[]){
            super(...props);
            this.flag = true;
        }
    }
}


@hasTrueFlag
class HasTrueFlagClass1 extends BaseClass { }

const HasTrueFlagClass2 = hasTrueFlag(class extends BaseClass { });

const b1 = new HasTrueFlagClass1().flag;
const b2 = new HasTrueFlagClass2().flag;
```

and generated .d.ts

```js
// index.d.ts
declare class BaseClass {
    flag: boolean;
    constructor();
}
declare function hasTrueFlag<T extends new (...props: any[]) => BaseClass>(base: T): typeof base & {
    new (): {
        flag: true;
    };
};
declare class HasTrueFlagClass1 extends BaseClass {
}
declare const HasTrueFlagClass2: {
    new (): {
        flag: boolean;
    };
} & (new () => {
    flag: true;
});
declare const b1: boolean;
declare const b2: boolean;
```

Here HasTrueFlagClass1 is presented in decorator's fashion and HasTrueFlagClass2 is presented by calling the decorator's function.

Can anyone help me understand:

1. Why neither b1 nor b2 can be inferred as `true`
2. Why `new () => { flag: true }` fails to override `{ new (): { flag: boolean } }` in .d.ts file

Comment: Notice that `a1` and `a2` are actually `undefined`. Despite your type declaration, the prototype objects do not have a `.flag` property when you use class field sytax.

Comment: The `new HasTrueFlagClass2()` has a type of `BaseClass`, because your decorator returns a `typeof BaseClass` and not a different type. And `BaseClass`'s `.flag` is declared as `boolean`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the prototype error. I've updated my question.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I understand there is an intersection invoked but shouldn't it collapse to `{ flag: true }` which is more narrowed?

Comment: I'm sorry. You're absolutely correct that's what it does do and should do.

Comment: @AluanHaddad then we come back to the original question: why b2 cannot be inferred as true. Its constructor is not decorated however calculated by a function thus instances’ type information seems well kept in the d.ts file.